# Dual Monitors, wont allow watching movie if monitor 1 is turned off

Tags: video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

I use 2 monitors, my 55" LED T.V for watching movies, and a 46" LED as my desktop monitor. I recently purchased a new video card, I am running windows 8.1 and use VLC for my media player.

Since the new video card, when I play a movie on monitor 2 and turn off monitor 1, the movie will automatically minimize and be sent back to monitor 1.

I really like to have the room dark without distractions when watching a movie.
How do I fix this?

Video card: AMD Radeon XFX R7 200 series.

Comment: The common denominator is the new video card, but you didn't even tell us the model, so no one will be able to give you device specific devices.  For this type of thing tho I'd check for updated software/drivers.

Comment: You didn't state what kind of video card aka Nvidia or ATI software you're using.

Comment: The new video card is a AMD Radeon XFX R7 200 series. The software has been updated.

Comment: try my suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, That worked. I just pressed windows key + P, selected duplicate, and restarted the PC. Looks like the resolution is lower though on both monitors. I could be wrong, just looks a little fuzzy.

Comment: checkmark my answer, if it's complete and answered your question

Answer (score 0):

Put the 2 monitors on Duplicate or Mirror.

you can do this by going into the software or

Press the windows key + P key and go to duplicate.

Comment: if nothing really works, you could set your background to black and remove your desktop icons ;p